# Mouse stops responding after changing dpi

Tags: 18.04, mouse

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.
Mouse model - Cougar 700M. 
After pressing dpi button mouse completely stops responding including cursor movement. It works fine on MacOS and Windows 10. I tried changing USB ports, but it didn't help.